# How to transpose Scala Dataframe from wide to long and back to long from wide

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to find out a problem here already but didn't get any so asking a new one. I have a dataframe which looks like:-

```
origin|destination|segment1_origin|segment1_dest|segment2_origin|segment2_dest|segment3_origin|segment3_dest|id
   del|        blr|            del|          pat|            pat|          bom|            bom|          blr|1
   ccu|        blr|            ccu|          pat|            pat|          bom|            bom|          blr|2
```

The task is to bring this in long format with desired output as:-

```
origin|destination|segment_origin|segment_dest|id
   del|        blr|           del|         pat|1
   del|        blr|           pat|         bom|1
   del|        blr|           bom|         blr|1
   ccu|        blr|           ccu|         pat|2
   ccu|        blr|           pat|         bom|2
   ccu|        blr|           bom|         blr|2
```

Post this I have to perform a join to update few columns like:-

```
origin|destination|segment_origin|segment_dest|id|distance
   del|        blr|           del|         pat|1 | 200
   del|        blr|           pat|         bom|1 | 300
   del|        blr|           bom|         blr|1 | 500
   ccu|        blr|           ccu|         pat|2 | 400
   ccu|        blr|           pat|         bom|2 | 300
   ccu|        blr|           bom|         blr|2 | 500
```

and then back to long format which should look like:-

```
origin|destination|segment1_origin|segment_-dest|segment1-ddistance|segment2_origin|segment2_dest|segment2_distance|segment3_origin|segment3_dest|segment3-distance|id
   del|        blr|            del|          pat|               200|            pat|          bom|              300|            bom|          blr|              500|1
   ccu|        blr|            ccu|          pat|               400|            pat|          bom|              300|            bom|          blr|              500|2
```

I tried breaking this using a for loop like below:-

```
var desiredDF = spark.emptyDataFrame
    for (i <- 1 to 3){
        val df = originalDS.selectExpr(s"segment${i}_origin as segment_origin",s"segment${i}_dest as segment_dest",
                "origin", "destination", "id")
        desiredDF = if (i == 1) df else desiredDF.union(df)
    }
desiredDf.join(refDF, (desiredDf("segment_origin") === refDF("origin")) && (desiredDS("segment_dest") === refDF("destination")))

here refDF contains origin, destination and distance
```

But with this I loose the information of segment whether it was segment 1 or 2 or 3 cause I have to bring back it wide format.

In python I see there are few supporting functions like "Melt" but I didn't find any similar for scala.
I'm using spark v 2.3
Even with the approach I just mentioned, I do not think this a good idea to use for loop and updating the mutable variable every time for a billion rows. Is there some better way to use this so that the segment info is preserved which can be used for again going to wide format?

Comment: why don't you just join the wide format table to the distance table directly? Just do the join three times and you're good. It's not optimal, but if you melt it, join it once, and pivot it, it's probably equally expensive

Comment: Actually it has in total 6 for which I'll have to make a join 6 times. and the originalDF here has over a billion rows. I tried that already and it gives out of memory error every time it goes for loop 5 or 6. Memory spill to Disk and Memory goes to approx 1.5TB. I already tried recursion also but that also didn't work. So thought of this transposing and then joining.

Comment: you should cache the dataframe after each join, instead of doing all 6 joins in one query. that will help save memory and disk